# Cast String as Date in GBQ

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query in Big Query where the payload.date is a string, and I would like to CAST this as a date. How can I do this using the sample query below?

I would like to have payload.date be a date and not a string.

`` SELECT count(number) FROM `sample_gbq_table` WHERE payload.event IN (30) AND payload.date >= '2022-04-27T00:00:01.000000+00:00' AND payload.date <= '2022-04-27T23:99:99.000000+00:00' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome Devin,

Here is an example query where I have used one of the dates you shared. In short, you can simply parse this string format of date into a date object using the `DATE()` function:

```sql
WITH date AS(
  SELECT
  "2022-04-27T00:00:01.000000+00:00" AS string_date
)

SELECT
string_date,
DATE(string_date) AS parsed_date
FROM date
```

You could thus rewrite your query as:

```sql
SELECT count(number) 
FROM `sample_gbq_table` 
WHERE payload.event IN (30) 
AND DATE(payload.date) = '2022-04-27'
```